connect to external ec2 with jenkins
I  am trying to connect external ec2 instance 172.20.160.4 and create a testfolder, but it is connecting to its own instance. and the result is "Connected to ip-165-14-265-120.us-east-2.compute.internal". And it creating testfolder on its own node.
agent {
        label 'smg-mitger'
    }
    
 stage('Connect to EC2 and Perform Operations') {
            steps {
                script {

                        sh '''
                        #!/bin/bash

                        echo "Attempting to connect to EC2 instance"
                        
                        ssh 172.20.160.4
                            echo "Connected to $(hostname)"
                            cd /home/ops
                            echo "Current directory:"
                            pwd
                            echo "Listing contents:"
                            ls -la
                            echo "Creating folder testfolder"
                            mkdir -p testfolder
                            echo "Folder created."
                            ls -la

                        '''

                }
            }
        }


Try using something like the SSH Steps PLugin for running your remote ssh commands

devops engineer did not give any details only private ip. asked me to login using ssh private ip and create a folder. but it connecting to its own node. i just have private ip and instance id. they have configured jenkins pipeline , added credentials

I think the only command executed in the EC2 instance is the first command echo "Connected to $(hostname)" the following command are executed on Jenkins machine if you need to execute all the commands on the remote EC2 you need to warp them in a script or use EOF as input :
        script {
                sh '''
                #!/bin/bash

                echo "Attempting to connect to EC2 instance"

                ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ec2-user@172.20.160.4 << 'EOF'
                    echo "Connected to $(hostname)"
                    cd /home/ops
                    echo "Current directory:"
                    pwd
                    echo "Listing contents:"
                    ls -la
                    echo "Creating folder testfolder"
                    mkdir -p testfolder
                    echo "Folder created."
                    ls -la
                EOF
                '''
            }

Hope this answer your question
